# How to use ng-repeat tag in jssor sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jssor

I am new to angular js and javascript. I have to integrate jssor into my project. For that, I am trying to use an array of sliders, but  the ng-repaet seems to be not working in jssor, it's showing an "undefined error". Could you please help me?

```
 <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
  <img u="image" ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)"ng-src="{{slide.img}}" />
 </div>

$scope.slides = [
                  {
                      img : 'https://careersites.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cmr/6.jpg',
                      thumb: 'http://www.vougageste.com/images/cartazes/1b94e20c15b26e99928401088da4a0bc.jpg'
                  },
                  {
                      img : 'https://careersites.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cmr/6.jpg',
                      thumb: 'https://diretodasaladeestar.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/encomenda.jpg'
                  },
                  {
                      img : 'https://careersites.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cmr/6.jpg',
                      thumb: 'http://comofas.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/encomendas.jpg',
                  }
              ];
    $scope. currentIndex=0;
     $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
                return $scope.currentIndex === index;
            };
```

}

Comment: did you include `slides`  array in the angular $scope?

Comment: yeah,the above is my slide array

Comment: can you add your `isCurrentSlideIndex` function to the code please

Answer (score 0):

Well the main problem with your code is that you didn't set the `ng-src` correctly, you set it with `slide.image` while it's `slide.img`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);
      app.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.slides = [
          {
            img : 'https://careersites.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cmr/6.jpg',
            thumb: 'http://www.vougageste.com/images/cartazes/1b94e20c15b26e99928401088da4a0bc.jpg'
          },
          {
            img : 'https://careersites.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cmr/6.jpg',
            thumb: 'https://diretodasaladeestar.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/encomenda.jpg'
          },
          {
            img : 'https://careersites.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cmr/6.jpg',
            thumb: 'http://comofas.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/encomendas.jpg',
          }
        ];
        $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function(idx) {
          if(idx === 1) return true;
          return false;
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="yourApp">
    <div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
        <img u="image" ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)" ng-src="{{slide.img}}" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Everything else should work good Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DJ7DZzd9NOVtzE6JygCW?p=preview)

Comment: sorry its not worked for me,in plunker also we get only one image ,images are not iterated while am trying to  do it but i was getting this error                                                                                                                        Error: after is undefined
$AnimateProvider</this.$get</<.enter@http://careers-cmr.hiregrid.io:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5455:9
ngRepeatTransclude@http://careers-cmr.hiregrid.io:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:29877:17

Comment: Exactly where are you using $AnimateProvider, can you explain a little more or edit you question please